# Production order of Battlestar Galactica (1978) episodes

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

*Star Trek* episodes might fictionally happen in airdate order, production order, or stardate order.

As well as I remember there was no mention of any kind of dates in *Battlestar Galactica* (1978) according to any Colonial dating system.  So that leaves two different obvious fictional orders for the episodes: airdate order and production order.

**Does anyone know the production order of *Battlestar Galactica* (1978) episodes?**

The [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Battlestar_Galactica_(1978_TV_series)_and_Galactica_1980_episodes) of *Battlestar Galactica* (1978) episodes gives the numbers in order of airing (the original air dates), and production codes that might give the order of production.

- s 1,2,3; "Saga of a Star World";original airdate September 17, 1978; production codes 50280, 50281, 50282.
- 4; "Lost Planet of the Gods Part 1"; September 24, 1978; 50204.
- 5; "Lost Planet of the Gods Part 2"; October 1, 1978; 50205.
- 6; "The Lost Warrior"; October 8, 1978; 50908.
- 7; "The Long Patrol"; October 15, 1978; 50902.
- 8; "Gun on Ice Planet Zero, Part 1" October 22, 1978; 50206.
- 9; "Gun on Ice Planet Zero, Part 2" October 29, 1978; 50207.
- 10; "The Magnificant Warriors" November 12, 1978; 50912.
- 11; "The Young Lords" November 19, 1978; 50905.
- 12; "The Living Legend, Part 1"; November 26, 1978; 50919.
- 13; "The Living Legend, Part 2"; December 3, 1978; 50920.
- 14; "Fire in Space"; December 17, 1978; 50917.
- 15; "War of the Gods, Part 1"; January 14, 1979; 50921.
- 16; "War of the Gods, Part 1"; January 21, 1979; 50922.
- 17; "The Man With Nine Lives"; January 28, 1979; 50916.
- 18; "Murder on the Rising Star"; February 18, 1979; 50918.
- 19; "Greetings from Earth"; February 25, 1979; 50926.
- 20; "Greetings from Earth"; February 25, 1979; 50947.
- 21; "Baltar's Escape"; March 11, 1979; 50927.
- 22: "Experiment in Terra"; March 18, 1979; 50928
- 23: "Take the Celestra"; April 1, 1979; 50929.
- 24; "The Hand of God"; April 29, 1979; 50930.

Assuming that the *Batlestar Galactica* TV movies produced first had the 502__ production codes and the episodes produced after it as turned into a weekly series have the 509__ production Codes, the order should be:

- s 1,2,3; "Saga of a Star World"; 50280, 50281, 50282.
- 4; "Lost Planet of the Gods Part 1"; 50204.
- 5; "Lost Planet of the Gods Part 2"; 50205.
- 6; "Gun on Ice Planet Zero, Part 1"; 50206.
- 7: "Gun on Ice Planet Zero, Part 2"; 50207.
- 8; "The Long Patrol"; 50902.
- 9; "The Young Lords"; 50905.
- 10; "The Lost Warrior"; 50908.
- 11; "The Magnificant Warriors"; 50912.
- 12; "The Man With Nine Lives"; 50916.
- 13: "Fire in Space"; 50917.
- 14; "Murder on the Rising Star"; 50918.
- 15; "The Living Legend, Part 1"; 50919.
- 16; "The Living Legend, Part 2"; 50920.
- 17; "War of the Gods, Part 1"; 50921.
- 18; "War of the Gods, Part 1"; 50922.
- 19; "Greetings from Earth"; February 25, 1979; 50926.
- 20; "Greetings from Earth"; February 25, 1979; 50947.
- 21; "Baltar's Escape"; March 11, 1979; 50927.
- 22: "Experiment in Terra"; March 18, 1979; 50928
- 23: "Take the Celestra"; April 1, 1979; 50929.
- 24; "The Hand of God"; April 29, 1979; 50930.